# how to highlight latex-syntax in org-mode but no effect on the produced PDF

Tags: emacs, syntax-highlighting, highlight, org-mode, emacs24

I use org-mode+LaTex to take scientific notes and produce them to PDFs, I can use

```
#+BEGIN_src latex:
  \begin{equation} 
   \int_\text{Birth}^{Death} work \mathrm{d} t = \text{LIFT}
  \end{equation}
 #+END_src
```

to highlight all latex codes between codes `#+BEGIN_src latex .... #+END` but if I don't delete this codes before I produce my org-document to PDF, I will get the unexpected `#+BEGIN_src latex` and `#+END` in the PDF.

Is there a more convenient way that can make latex syntax highlighted in org-mode with no unexpected codes left in PDF?

I searched some info about highlight source codes in org-mode, however, it seem no one concerns my demand that I simply only need the function of highlights of the latex syntax to make me edit easily, not the highlights in the resulting PDF.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The (first?) problem is the colon after "latex" on the first line.